# Initialize several global variables using an array

Tags: c#

Lets say I have the class

```
class Foo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

And I have the global variables:

```
public static Foo A1 { get; set; }
public static Foo A2 { get; set; }
public static Foo A3 { get; set; }
public static Foo A4 { get; set; }
// etc... more
```

---

The following code will not set the value of those global variables:

```
var elementsToSet = new Foo[]{A1,A2,A3,A4}; 

for (var i = 0; i < elementsToSet.Length; i++)            
       elementsToSet[i] = new Foo {Value = i};
```

In other words `A1 == null`   is true :(

**I am trying to initialize A1, A2, etc not the array**

---

**how can I prevent having to do:**

```
A1 = new Foo { Value = 1 };
A2 = new Foo { Value = 2 };
A3 = new Foo { Value = 3 };
A4 = new Foo { Value = 4 };
// etc...
```

---

### PS

**I know I can have an array as my global variable instead of several. I am just asking this question to learn.** I have the reference of each variable. I want to set a new variable of the same type at that address.

### Also

If `Foo` will have been a struct instead of a reference type (class) this will work no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your array `elementsToSet` at first contains four instances of `null` (because `A1`, `A2`, ... `A4` are all `null` originally). Then when you set each of `elementsToSet[i]` to a `new Foo(...)` the elements in the *array* are set, but none of the elements are references to your `A1` ... `A4` `Foo`s.

Really, the best ways to do this are

1. Initialize each `Foo`, one per line. This can get annoying if you have a lot of them.
2. Have your global variables be in an array, and then loop through and initialize.
3. Use reflection (the worst idea).

**Edit for the question's edit:** No, your original code will still not work if `Foo` is a struct instead of a class, because then setting the `elementsToSet[i]`, even when `elementsToSet` is initialized with `A1` ... `A4`, will still just set the elements in the array. Even *more so*, the original `A1` ... `A4` are not being set through the array.

Comment: If I have to initialize each Foo to something not null I might as well set its value when I initialize it. I guess its impossible if they are null :/. People hate reflection lol. Thanks for the help I think there is no solution so I will accept this answer as a solution.

Comment: Reflection is a solution (and one that would work) but as you say. Few people like it (often for poorly justified reasons)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I prevent having to do

The idea is to write a method that will:

1. create a new object for a parameter passed by reference
2. assign parameter with a newly created object
3. add object to some collection

This can be implemented in a generic class:

```
Public Class Builder(Of ItemType)

    Dim Constructor As Func(Of Integer, ItemType)
    Dim Queue As New Queue(Of ItemType)

    Public Sub New(Constructor As Func(Of Integer, ItemType))
        Me.Constructor = Constructor
    End Sub

    Public Function Build(ByRef Item As ItemType) As Builder(Of ItemType)
        Item = Constructor(Queue.Count)
        Queue.Enqueue(Item)
        Return Me
    End Function

    Public Function Items() As IEnumerable(Of ItemType)
        Return Queue
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim Foos = New Builder(Of Foo)(Function(Index) New Foo With {.Value = Index + 1}).
    Build(A1).Build(A2).Build(A3).Build(A4).
    Items
```

Comments:

1. `Builder` uses a `Constructor` delegate to create each object. `Constructor` delegate is passed into `Builder` constructor.
2. `Build` function behaves as stated above and returns `Builder` to chain calls
3. `Items` function returns an enumeration of created items
4. `Builder` can be used for any class, not only Foo